# Strange += operater issue in Javascript/jQuery where NaN is being returned instead of numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators, nan

The issue is with the line `total += parseInt($(el).val());` If e.g. `parseInt($(el).val())` holds the value 200 (which I confirmed with an alert) the value set to Total is NaN.
If I remove the + so that `total = parseInt($(el).val());` then total will return the value 200 and not NaN.
Can anyone see what's causing this NaN issue?
Thanks

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#courses').on('change', e => {
    $('#targetPane').load(e.target.value);
    path = (e.target.value);
    //open callback function
    $('#targetPane').load('path', function() {
      //open callback contents 
      function getTotal() {
        var total = 0;
        $("input, select").each(function(i, el) {
          if ($(el).is("input:checked")) {
            $($(el).data("rel")).show();
            total += parseInt($(el).val());
            alert("total=" + total);
          } else {
            $($(el).data("rel")).hide();
          }
          if ($(el).is("select")) {
            if ($(el).val() !== "0") {
              $($(el).data("rel")).html($(el).val()).show();
              total += parseInt($(el).val());
            }
          }
        });
        return total;
      }
      $('input[type="checkbox"], select').change(function() {
        //$(document).on('change', 'input', 'select', function() {
        $("#sum").text(getTotal());
      });

      //close callback contents   
    }); //close callback function
  });
}); //close jQuery
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.load Test</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/grid/">
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/grid/grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="py-4">
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <select name="myCourses" id="courses" autocomplete="off">
          <option value="" selected>Select</option>
          <option value="includes/inc_1_working.html">Load inc_1.html</option>
          <!-- assume more dropdown options -->
        </select>
        <!-- load include file here -->
        <div id="targetPane"></div>
      </div>
      <!--close row-->
    </div>
    <!-- close container -->
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Loaded in file below: includes/inc_1_working.html

```
<table width="100%" id="form1">
  <tr><div id="test"></div>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="n1" value="200" data-rel="div.n1"> Show Price1
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="n1 box">200</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="n2" value="200" data-rel="div.n2"> Show Price
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="n2 box">200</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="n3" value="200" data-rel="div.n3"> Show Price
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="n3 box">200</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <select id="n4" data-rel="div.n4">
          <option value="0" selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="10">item 1</option>
          <option value="20">item 2</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="n4"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <select id="n5" data-rel="div.n5">
          <option value="0" selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="3">item 1</option>
          <option value="4">item 2</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="n5"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Total: </td>
    <td>
      <div id='sum'>0</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If just one of those values you're adding to `total` is empty string, `parseInt('')` returns `NaN` ... once `total` is `NaN` no amount of adding will fix it - try `total += parseInt($(el).val()) || 0;`

Comment: Thanks `total += parseInt($(el).val()) || 0;` wasn't it. The NaN is starting at `total += parseInt($(el).val());` under `if ($(el).is("select")) {` so there's a conflict between the value in the select dropdowns. I wonder can I target a select with (#mySelect select) in that getTotal function. I am using a select dropdown on that page to load a file and I'm using select dropdowns in the loaded file `includes/inc_1_working.html`  - jQuery .load()

Comment: huh? did I say you should only put that `|| 0` in one place? no ... both places will do

Comment: There are no checkboxes in your HTML. Do they all have numeric values?

Comment: "The NaN is starting at total += parseInt($(el).val());" ... so ... make it `total += parseInt($(el).val()) || 0;` like I said

Comment: Unrelated problem: The `<select>` doesn't have a `data-rel` attribute. So `$($(el).data("rel")).hide();` won't work.

Comment: `$("#form1 input, #form1 select").each(function(i, el) {` and `if ($(el).is("#form1 select")) {` SEEM to have fixed it

Comment: Don't add event handlers inside other event handler. Every time you click on `#courses` you'll add another `change` handler to the select and checkboxes.

Comment: @Narmar - unless this is the entirety of the code, you can't be sure that there's no code that sets the jquery.data - which has nothing to do with data- attributes (I was mistaken) - *Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data- attribute value, use attr*

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I have to investigate what you mean there. Learning still

Comment: Thanks guys I'll digest that info if I run into more issues. The loaded in file has data rels like `<input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" id="n1" value="200" data-rel="div.n1"> Show Price1`

Comment: i just added the loaded in file above in the main question (at the end)

Comment: @Bravo @Barmer  Hi, so the only code I had to change in the main code above is `$('input[type="checkbox"], select').change(function() {` to `$("#targetPane input, #targetPane select").each(function(i, el) {` .Strangely though the checkboxes load up unchecked and showing values when they should only show values when checked. Any idea to uncheck all the checkboxes on script load? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery.load Test</title> 
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/grid/">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            
        jQuery($ => {
                            $('#courses').on('change', e => {
                                $('#targetPane').load(e.target.value);
                                path = (e.target.value);
                                //open callback function
                                   $('#targetPane').load('path', function(){
                                     //open callback contents 
                                    
                                    //hide all values
                                     $("#targetPane input, #targetPane select").each(function(i, el) {
                                        $($(el).data("rel")).hide();
                                    });
                                     
                                    function getTotal() {
                                        
                                            var total = 0;
                                            $("#targetPane input, #targetPane select").each(function(i, el) {
                                                
                                            if ($(el).is("input:checked")) {
                                                $($(el).data("rel")).show();
                                                total += parseInt($(el).val());
                                                
                                            } else {
                                                $($(el).data("rel")).hide();
                                            }
                                            if ($(el).is("select")) {
                                                if ($(el).val() !== "0") {
                                                $($(el).data("rel")).html($(el).val()).show();
                                                total += parseInt($(el).val());
                                                
                                                }
                                            }
                                            });
                                            
                                            return total;
                                            
                                        }

                                        $('select #courses').change(function() {
                                            $($(el).data("rel")).hide(getTotal());
                                        });

                                        $('#targetPane input[type="checkbox"], #targetPane select').change(function() {
                                        //$(document).on('change', 'input', 'select', function() {
                                        $("#sum").text(getTotal());
                                        });
                                    
                                       //close callback contents   
                                   }); //close callback function
                            });  
                        }); //close jQuery
    </script>
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/grid/grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="py-4">
    <main>
      <div class="container">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                <select name="myCourses" id="courses" autocomplete="off">
                    <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                    <option value="includes/inc_1_working.html">Load inc_1.html</option>
                    <!-- assume more dropdown options -->
                </select>
                <!-- load include file here -->
                <div id="targetPane"></div>
                </div>  <!--close row-->      
        </div> <!-- close container -->
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove arrow fuction jquery ready
add old style work for me

Answer (score 0):

Replace parseInt() with Number()